# How to change time from 24 to 12 hour format in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-pipe

I have used input type `time` in my application to receive time:

```
  <mat-input-container>
<input matInput  formControlName="start_time" type="time" placeholder="Time Start">
<p class="invalid-text" *ngIf="dvrForm.controls.start_time.invalid &&
        (dvrForm.controls.start_time.dirty || dvrForm.controls.start_time.touched)">
  <span *ngIf="dvrForm.controls.start_time.errors.required"> Start Time is required.</span></p>
```

And after i store data through input it gets stored in 24 hour format :

[image: View Of database how the time is stored]

So now when I display it in my view it gets displayed in the same format eg:    `23:11:00` , is it possible to use something like pipes to convert it into 12 hr format while displaying in the view.

Comment: There are pipes to convert whole time stamp into some formats ,not to Time specifically IMO

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do it from pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'convertFrom24To12Format'})
export class TimeFormat implements PipeTransform {
     transform(time: any): any {
         let hour = (time.split(':'))[0]
         let min = (time.split(':'))[1]
         let part = hour > 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
         if(parseInt(hour) == 0)
          hour = 12;
         min = (min+'').length == 1 ? `0${min}` : min;
         hour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
         hour = (hour+'').length == 1 ? `0${hour}` : hour;
         return `${hour}:${min} ${part}`
       }
   }
```

In your html for example:

```
<p>Time Format From  24 to 12 : {{'23:11:00' | convertFrom24To12Format}}</p>
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Shouldn't `let part = hour > 12 ? 'pm' : 'am'` be `let part = hour >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am'`

Comment: Is there any way to get the time format from system locale?

Comment: and what about revert solution? from 12 to 24 format

Answer (score 8):

With Pipe you can achive it you **need to use hh for 12h and HH for 24h**

```js
var value = element(by.binding('example.value | date: "HH:mm:ss"'));
    var valid = element(by.binding('myForm.input.$valid'));

    function setInput(val) {
      var scr = "var ipt = document.getElementById('exampleInput'); " +
      "ipt.value = '" + val + "';" +
      "angular.element(ipt).scope().$apply(function(s) { s.myForm[ipt.name].$setViewValue('" + val + "'); });";
      browser.executeScript(scr);
    }
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="timeExample">
      <script>
     angular.module('timeExample', [])
       .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.example = {
           value: new Date()
         };
       }]);
    </script>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
       <label for="exampleInput">Pick a time and Change AM to PM</label>
       <input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
           placeholder="HH:mm:ss"  required /><br/>
       <tt>value in 12H = {{example.value | date: "hh:mm:ss"}}</tt><br/>
       
       <tt>value 24H = {{example.value | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</tt>

    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: i dont recieve the value in time stamp format, as I mentioned I receive time in time format that is `11:11:00` due to which i get the error `DvrListComponent.html:40 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '11:11:00' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Comment: '11:11:00' is not a timestamp, it is a string. If you have to start dealing with timezones, a string is insufficient. Converting a timestamp with HH instead of hh should be the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, using the default Angular pipe reference ***UPPERCASE*** `HH.mm` instead of `hh.mm`

`today: Date = new Date('2020-12-12T18:00');`

```
<div> {{ today | date : 'hh.mm' }}</div>
// 06.00
<div>{{ today | date : 'HH.mm' }}</div>
// 18.00
```

Comment: this is the most simple answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use mediumTime, this displays like '10:30:24 AM'

{{start_time|date:'mediumTime':'undefined':'en-US' }}

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert the time from 24 hours to 12 hours format using moment library. You can create a custom pipe to achieve it. Refer the following youtube link it solves the similar issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKE1d9o_Kmk

Comment: Would not reccommend using moment.
'Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library.'

https://github.com/moment/moment

Comment: @LarsRødal, Yes I know that, With that the Moment.js team has also announced as "_ It is not dead, but it is indeed done._". Which means, they’ll fix any serious issues but new features or changes are off the table. So I don't see any reason for down voting this answer. And definitely we can use moment existing features in our project till it is announced as officially dead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Datepipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

You can pass the Datepipe the locale parameter which determines how your date is displayed.

e.g

```
{{this.testDate | date:'short':'undefined':'en-US'}}
```

will display as
11:20 AM

```
{{this.testDate | date:'short':'undefined':'de-GER'}}
```

will display as 
16.05.18, 11:20

You could also set your localeid in the app-module.ts to get the behaviour

app-module.ts

```
import localeEnGb from '@angular/common/locales/en-GB'
registerLocaleData(localeEnGb );
...
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-GB' }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,
{{'1970-01-01 ' + start_time | date: 'h:mm:ss a'}}

Reason is input string should always be a valid date with a time